# How do I randomly generate an output from a Google Sheet in the R Shiny app?

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny

I am trying to build an application where a database of songs with their artist and genre on Google Sheets is drawn from to create an output on Shiny. I'd like to use some sort of filtering to either generate a random selection from a list of songs within their genre and other selected inputs. I'm fairly new to Shiny and am having difficulty with this. Any tips are appreciated! Here is my code so far as well as the Google Sheets link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wzt5w-yyHYvkYuZIj4gHPcZS6deFNBc-H_hM_vJKPDk/edit?usp=sharing

```
read_rds("data-processed/01-cleaned_data.rds")

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  headerPanel("KVRX Hot 100: The Mobile Application"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("no1", "Genre:",
                c("Blues" = "blues",
                  "Rock" = "rock",
                  "Pop" = "pop",
                  "Disco" = "disco",
                  "Folk" = "folk",
                  "Country" = "country",
                  "Indie" = "indie",
                  "House Music/EDM" = "edm",
                  "Reggae" = "reggae",
                  "Classical" = "classical",
                  "Korean" = "korean",
                  "Punk" = "punk",
                  "Afro-pop" = "afro-pop",
                  "Metal" = "metal",
                  "Funk/Soul" = "soul",
                  "Brazillian" = "brazil",
                  "Korean" = "korean",
                  "Indie rock" = "indie rock",
                  "Electronic" = "electronic",
                  "Metal" = "metal",
                  "Alternative" = "alt",
                  "Hip-hop/Rap" = "hh/rap",
                  "Jazz" = "jazz",
                  "Worldwide" = "ww",
                  "Ambient" = "ambient",
                  "Indian" = "indian",
                  "Alt folk" = "alt folk",
                  "Electronic" = "electronic",
                  "Indie rock" = "indie rock",
                  "Europe" = "europe",
                  "Psychedelic" = "psych",
                  "Hard bop" = "hard bop",
                  "Cajun" = "cajun",
                  "Christian" = "christian")),
    # checkboxInput("outliers", "Show outliers", TRUE),
    selectInput("no2", "Explicit:",
                c("Explicit" = "explicit",
                  "Clean" = "clean")),
    selectInput("no3", "Texan Artist",
                c("Texan" = "texan",
                  "Not Texan" = "not-texan")),
    actionButton("btn", "Generate"),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("Song")
  ),
 mainPanel(
textOutput("Song")
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {
calculate <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
input$no1 + input$no2
})
output$total <- renderText({
calculate()
})
}

  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your approach is right but logic testing outside shiny is easier. Have u tested it on a data frame itself first to generate a random item (from your selections and inputs) without shiny environment. If that works, just use that logic in shiny server - within observe even where you are calculating it in `calculate()`.  Also avoid using variable IDs like btn etc (since there are css classes etc of same name too).  I will post some idea as answer to let your calculate() work but you need to check as I cannot work on your data as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach (I don't have access to your `.rds` object, but this shiny app (below), directly pulls from the google sheet link. Notice that I do not use `no3`, the input that selects if Texan or Not-Texan, as I do not have access to that. Also, my `get_songs()` function currently pulls 5 songs at random. You might want to pull them all, or you might want to add a UI element that allows the user to set the desired number of songs.

```
library(googlesheets4)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)

# set to read only
gs4_deauth()

# get data
data = read_sheet(
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wzt5w-yyHYvkYuZIj4gHPcZS6deFNBc-H_hM_vJKPDk/edit?usp=sharing",
  col_types="c"
)

# get genre choices
genres = unique(data %>% filter(!is.na(`Genres:`)) %>% pull(`Genres:`))

# drop extra column ("Genres:") and rename
data <- data %>% 
  select(-`Genres:`) %>% 
  rename_all(~c("Explicit", "Genre_code", "TRT", "Song", "Artist", "Genre_str", "song_id"))

get_songs <- function(g,e,n=5) {
  result = data %>% 
    filter(Genre_str %in% g, Explicit == e) %>% 
    select(Song, Artist, Genre = Genre_str)
  
  # could be less than n songs returned
  if(nrow(result)==0) return(NULL)
  
  if(nrow(result)<n) return(result) 
  else return(sample_n(result,n))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  headerPanel("KVRX Hot 100: The Mobile Application"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("no1", "Genre:",choices=genres),
      selectInput("no2", "Explicit:",choices=c("Clean", "Explicit")),
      selectInput("no3", "Texan Artist",choices= c("Texan" = "texan","Not Texan" = "not-texan")),
      actionButton("btn", "Generate")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("Songs")
    )
  )
)
  

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  songs = eventReactive(input$btn, {
    get_songs(input$no1, input$no2)
  })
  
  output$Songs <- renderTable(
    songs()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```